# java: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/liblapack.so.3: undefined symbol: ATL_dGetNB

Tags: debian, apache-spark

I am using spark 1.2.1 and during the SVD computing i am receiving this error:

```
java: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/liblapack.so.3: undefined symbol: ATL_dGetNB
```

I tried to change `liblapack.so.3` to ATLAS, but didn't help.

There are 2 choices for the alternative liblapack.so.3 (providing /usr/lib/liblapack.so.3).

```
  Selection    Path                                      Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/lib/lapack/liblapack.so.3             10        auto mode
* 1            /usr/lib/atlas-base/atlas/liblapack.so.3   5         manual mode
  2            /usr/lib/lapack/liblapack.so.3             10        manual mode
```

Any ideas what is wrong with it? I done with the googling, found nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Try : sudo update-alternatives --set liblapack.so.3gf /usr/lib/lapack/liblapack.so.3gf

Actually you can have a look at [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/atlas/+bug/1005219)